# How to get header from SSR response in Next.js

Tags: reactjs, next.js, jwt

I am working on web application rendered via getServerSideProps in Next.js. In function getServerSideProps I set authorization token into header, but currently I am struggling how to get this token from header.

My code:

```
export async function getServerSideProps(ctx: NextPageContext) {
  const token: string = "Sample token"
  ctx.res?.setHeader("Authorization", token);

  return {
    props: {}
  }
}

const HomePage: NextPage<{}> = ({}) => {
  const token: string = "how to get token here?"

  return (
  )
}

export default HomePage
```

I am able to see the token in response via browser.
[image]

Thanks for any advice!

Comment: Can you clarify what's the reason for setting an `Authorization` header inside `getServerSideProps`?

Answer (score 1):

In `getServerSideProps` you return your token and in Homepage you get it by props

```
export async function getServerSideProps(ctx: NextPageContext) {
    const token: string = "Sample token"
    ctx.res?.setHeader("Authorization", token);
  
    return {
      props: {
        token
      }
    }
  }
  
  const HomePage: NextPage<{}> = ({ token }) => {
    console.log(token)
  
    return (
    )
  }
  
  export default HomePage
```

Comment: Ahhh, in your solution token is stored in 2 places, in header and in body of response. I need it in the header for testing purposes. Maybe I am perfectionist, but is there a way to do it only via header?

Comment: i think you should store token in cookie, so it can be read in both server and client side

Comment: I guess so there is no better solution for this. Thanks.

Comment: cookies should never be read on client side to prevent XSS threats. httponly flag should always be set.